# Connect QMediaContent to RTP stream

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, qt5

I have created an RTP stream with ffmpeg and made the SDP file from what it printed out.

I can connect ffplay to the stream by reading the sdp file.

What is the correct url to give to QMediaContent to connect it to a RTP stream by giving it a local / remote SDP file?